# Fetch an ID from a URL and pass it to the laravel controller in VueJS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to submit a form which is in Vue and my route is

```
http://cricketstats.test/en/dashboard/players/z2d4ca09a7/india/941/runs
```

Here `941` is the player id. I want this id also to be passed to the laravel controller along with the remaining form data.

Is there have anyway to fetch this id from the url in vue, and pass it to the laravel controller?

Comment: Have you tried using axios/ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple code below will extract what you need.

After this, all you need to do is make an ajax/axios request going to the controller.

```
var url = 'http://cricketstats.test/en/dashboard/players/z2d4ca09a7/india/941/runs';
var url_split = url.split("/");
var my_id_location = url_split.length - 2;
var my_id = url_split[my_id_location];
console.log(my_id );
```

Here's an idea about how you can send the data to the controller using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/your/url",
  method: 'POST',
  data: {id:my_id, _token:token},
  success: function(data) {
    //if success
  }
});
```

Comment: okay,  here i'm having small question, when passing this value to the controller how can I do it, because it's not a form data, hence i can't use formData.append, right?

Comment: i have updated the answer and used ajax instead of axios for simplicity.